# Does API key actually identifies tenant in a multi-tenant application?

Tags: rest, integration, multi-tenant

for modern SaaS multi-tenant public cloud applications. I noticed that they would have a common API for integration, all I need is the API key in my request headers to properly retrieve data specific to my tenant.

My question is does the API key actually identifies which tenant I am requesting data for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes, that is how you get to identify the tenant. The API key will be obtained under the context of the tenant.

- The API key can be in encrypted format which will have the tenant identifier as part of it.

(OR)

- The API key can be hashed in this case you will send the tenant identifier and other parameters to arrive at the hash (recompute) so that the SaaS provider will infer the tenant information from the API keyitself.